# Combining two PowerShell do..while statements

Tags: powershell

I have two PowerShell `do..while` statements that work great separately.  However, I want to combine them and use the logic of both.

The code below is split into 3 sections.  The first is full of variable declarations that cover both statements.  The second is the first Do-While statement that causes the script not to move forward with other processes until the IE webpage has fully loaded.  The third section has the second Do-While statement which strictly returns a "loading" statement until the process has loaded, and then returns a "loaded" statement.

I want to combine these correctly so that the script sits in the loop until the page has loaded returning a "loading" statement, and then states "loaded" and moves on with life.

```
$elementID = "loginHeader"
$elementMatchText = "Pick an account"
$timeoutMilliseconds = 5000
$timeStart = Get-Date
$exitFlag = $false
$started = $false
$ie = (New-Object -Com SXcript.Shell).Run("http://www.msn.com", 3)

do {
    sleep -Milliseconds 100
    if ( $ie.ReadyState -eq 4 ) {
        $elementText = (($ie.Document).GetElementByID($elementID )).InnerText
        $elementMatch = $elementText -match $elementMatchText
    }
    $timeout = ((Get-Date).Subtract($timeStart)).TotalMilliseconds -gt $timeoutMilliseconds
    $exitFlag = $elementMatch -or $timeout
} until ( $exitFlag )
Start-Sleep -m 500
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")

do {
    $status = Get-Process iexplore
    if (!($status)) {
        Write-Host 'Internet Explorer is starting';
        Start-Sleep -m 100
    } else {
        Write-Host 'Internet Explorer has started';
        $started = $true
    }
} until ($started)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest them, with an `if` condition to only run the second loop once the criteria of the first loop has been fulfilled.

```
Do {
    sleep -milliseconds 100
    If ( $ie.ReadyState -eq 4 ) {
        $elementText = (($ie.Document).getElementByID($elementID )).innerText
        $elementMatch = $elementText -match $elementMatchText
    }

    $timeout = ((Get-Date).subtract($timeStart)).TotalMilliseconds -gt $timeoutMilliseconds
    $exitFlag = $elementMatch -or $timeout

    if($exitFlag){
        Start-Sleep -m 500
        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
        Do {
            $status = Get-Process iexplore
            If (!($status)) { Write-Host 'Internet Explorer is starting' ; Start-Sleep -m 100}
            Else { Write-Host 'Internet Explorer has started' ; $started = $true }
        }
        Until ($started)
    }
} Until ($exitFlag)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I knew nesting is what I wanted, but I could not figure out the correct way to do it.  You made it work great.